# detecting network after view loaded in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i am using ionic framework. what i want is that the app should display one card if network is available and other card if no-network is available.

i have the following code in my controller

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {

init=function(){
 alert(navigator.connection.type);
}

  init();
})
```

the alert returns 0 zero not sure why that is.

so i tried to hook up a button and see the same code

```
<button ng-click="demo()" class="button button-positive">get network</button>
```

and in the controller

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.demo=function(){
  alert(navigator.connection.type);
  }
})
```

now i do get the correct result so i get wifi,2g etc

so i think that angular is executing before the navigator.connection.type is resolved.

How do i detect the network on view load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't start your app until the device is ready

```
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() { 
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['YourAppName']);
  }, false);
  var YourAppName = angular.module('YourAppName', []);
```

Comment: where do I have to put this? In the app.js?

Comment: I don't know your app structure, wherever the module is called